# Objective C AttributedString in UITextView - Messaging app

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have an iphone messaging application in which users can send text based messages to each other. I'm using find and replace code (as outlined below) so that every time a user types a certain word, for example "stackoverflow" it is replaced by the same word but with a predetermined hyperlink - all this happens as the user types.

The find and replace code works fine however when using the code below to output the hyperlink as an NSAttributedString within the UITextView i get a literal output of the hyperlink:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
initWithString:@"stackoverflow" attributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName: 
@"http://stackoverflow.com"}];
```

Find and replace array:

```
self.words = @{
                   @"stackoverflow": attributedString,
}
```

Find and replace execution:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *lastCharacter = [textView.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([textView.text length]-1, 1)];
    if([lastCharacter isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        NSMutableArray *words = (NSMutableArray *)[textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSString *lastWord = words[words.count - 2];
        for (NSString *word in self.words.allKeys) {
            if ([lastWord isEqualToString:word]) {
                lastWord = self.words[word];
                [words replaceObjectAtIndex:words.count - 2 withObject:lastWord];
                textView.text = [words componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not having the desired effect - the find and replace literally outputs

stackoverflow {NSLink = "http://stackoverflow.com";} in the text box

i.e.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here, is there another solution?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I didn't understood exactly what you're doing, but I say that you're mixing `NSAttributedString` and `NSString`. `lastWord` is a `NSAttributedString`, not a `NSString`, so when you replace by it, you replace it by its description.

Comment: Hi Larme, indeed, this is exactly whats happening, is it possible to insert hyperlinks into NSStrings?

Comment: No. Except if you replace it directly with the URL, and you autorise data detectors.